# Cálculo de potência

Tags: c, array

> Fazer um programa que receba um vetor de 200 posições (int)
>
> Crie em seguida uma função que retorne a potência ao quadrado de cada elemento do vetor.
>
> O programa principal deve exibir todos os resultados na tela.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std; 

int x, base, resp = 0, vet[200];

int calc(int base, int resp){

    resp = (base * base); 

    return resp;    
}
main(){   
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese") ;

    for (x = 0; x < 200; x++) {
        vet[x] = x;
        cout << endl << "Posição " << x + 1 << " : " << vet[x];
    }

    for (x = 0; x < 200; x++) {
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl << vet[x] << "² =  " << calc(vet[x], resp);
    }

    getch();
}
```

Onde está o erro? Não roda.

Comment: O protótipo da main está correto ? -- `int main( int argc, char ** argv )`

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Comment: Se quiser pode sinalizar que a pergunta fique anônima mas não edite ela de forma que sem contexto  ou radicalmente.

Answer (score 1):

O código é bem confuso, tem coisas que não é bem C++, mas pra exercício vai. Eu acho que essa função `calc()` é desnecessária neste caso, mas o maior problema que eu vejo é não estar usando a função de potência ([`pow()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow)), que parece ser o objetivo. Mesmo o algoritmo é esquisito e dá pra fazer melhor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std; 

int calc(int base) {
    return pow(base, 2);
}

int main() {   
    int vet[200];
    for (int x = 0; x < 200; x++) {
        vet[x] = x;
        cout << endl << "Posição " << x + 1 << " : " << vet[x];
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < 200; x++) cout << endl << vet[x] << "² =  " << calc(vet[x]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/XOCIgC). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rzkqznga-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/Power.cpp).

Answer (score 0):

1) Você está trabalhando com variáveis globais, essa escolha não é muito indicada. Geralmente o uso de variáveis globais são para definir, por exemplo `float pi = 3.1415;`, esse valor não será alterado, em códigos pequenos o uso de variáveis globais pode não ser notado mas, a medida que o código cresce seu uso começa a mostrar seus problemas. Por exemplo, quando se trabalha com microcontroladores e programação de sistemas embarcados esse tipo de definição é comum, pois evita desperdiçar memoria.

2)Você precisa apenas da base

```
int pot2(int base){
   return base*base;
}
```

3) Caso opte pela função da biblioteca cmath pode executar como já foi dito aqui nessa discussão pelo Maniero